# selecting rows using the enum field in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select, enums

I am facing an abnormal issue with the enum field(UserStatus) of my table(userinfo). The table structure is as follows:

```
Field       Type        Default
------------------------------------------
Id          int(11)       (NULL)
FirstName   varchar(50)   (NULL)
LastName    varchar(50)   (NULL)
....        ...           ...
....        ...           ...   
UserStatus  enum('0','1') (NULL)
```

Here I have rows with the UserStatus values as NULL, 0 and 1. But When I am trying to select rows on the basis of the UserStatus field like:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    userinfo 
WHERE 
    UserStatus<>'1'
```

Its not working and resulting in an empty resultset.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remember that `NULL <> '1'` is `NULL` and therefore falsy!  Have you tried `UserStatus <> 1 OR UserStatus IS NULL`?

Comment: Why not use `BIT` column type?

Comment: @cdhowie : Thanks man, it worked for the UserStatus<>'1' by using the condition NotMine <> '1' OR NotMine IS NULL

Comment: @Pushpendra Glad it worked.  I've converted my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that `NULL <> '1'` is itself `NULL` and therefore your condition won't match rows whose `UserStatus` is `NULL`.  Use this expression instead:

```
UserStatus IS NULL OR UserStatus <> '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be a better structure, if you would give a default value and make the field `NOT NULL` but in this case you could use

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM userinfo 
 WHERE ifnull(UserStatus, '0') <> '1'
```